# Sort Columns on Angularjs DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I want to sort my table columns by angular-dataTables. However, it sort the productCurrency because of 'ng-if' first then only to sort the productType. Any suitable function of dataTable can sort the table correctly? Check my output:

My Output:

```
|Product     |
|CHN Product1|
|USD Product1|
|ABC         |
|BBC         |
|BBC         |
|ZBC         |
```

Expected Output:

```
|Product     |
|ABC         |
|BBC         |
|BBC         |
|CHN Product1|
|USD Product1|
|ZBC         |
```

You can see it was supposed to sort product by alphabet, but it sort by currency 1st then the product type.

(Edited) PS: USD & CHN is productCurrency; Product1, ABC, BBC, ZBC is productType.

Here are my code:

ViewUserType.html

```
<td>
    <span ng-if="ctrl.productType='ABC'" translate="ctrl.productCurrency.translateKey"> {{ctrl.productCurrency}}</span>
    <span translate="ctrl.product.type.translateKey">{{ctrl.productType}}</span>
</td>
```

Controller.js

```
ctrl.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('aaSorting', [[2, 'desc'], [1, 'desc']]).withOption('pageLength', 25);
```

Comment: try changing the `aaSorting` to `order` like `withOption('order', [[2, 'desc'], [1, 'desc']])`

Comment: I dont quite get it. You talk about `productType` but render out `"User Type"`. If you just concatenate and want to sort alphabetically, then the code does as expected, but you want to sort the column on `"User Type"`, which is `Product1` and `Product1` in the example? Besides that your `ng-if` should be an evaluation not an assignment.

Comment: @davidkonrad It was a typo for "User Type", I edited the question. I want to concatenate it but it will also have to concatenate the translate key also, and it will be very troubling for me to add all the translate key. It would be better if I can find a dynamic way to sort the string by alphabet.

Comment: @jitender I tried and it won't works.